# Padding elements of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say that I have the following `numpy array`:

```
[[1,1,1]
 [1,1,1]
 [1,1,1]]
```

And I need to pad each element in the array with a zero on either side (rather then `numpy.pad()` which pads rows and columns). This ends up as follows:

```
[ [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]
  [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]
  [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0] ]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this then creating an empty array and using nested loops?

**Note:** My preference is as fast and memory light as possible. Individual arrays can be up to 12000^2 elements and I'm working with 16 of them at the same time so my margins are pretty thin in 32 bit

**Edit:**  Should have specified but the padding is not always 1, padding must be variable as I am up-sampling data by a factor dependent on the array with the highest resolution.  given 3 arrays with the shapes (121,121) ; (1200,1200) ; (12010,12010) I need to be able to pad the first two arrays to a shape of (12010,12010) (I know that these numbers don't share common factors, this isn't a problem as being within an index or two of the actual location is acceptable, this padding is just needed to get them into the same shape, rounding out the numbers by padding the rows at the ends is acceptable)

**Working Solution:** an adjustment of @Kasramvd solution does the trick.  Here is the code that fits my application of the problem.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])

print(a)

x, y = a.shape
factor = 3
indices = np.repeat(np.arange(y + 1), 1*factor*2)[1*factor:-1*factor]

a=np.insert(a, indices, 0, axis=1)

print(a)
```

results in:

```
 [[1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]]

 [[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the related indices with `np.repeat` based on array's shape, then insert the 0 in that indices.

```
>>> def padder(arr, n):
...     x, y = arr.shape
...     indices = np.repeat(np.arange(y+1), n*2)[n:-n]
...     return np.insert(arr, indices, 0, axis=1)
... 
>>> 
>>> padder(a, 1)
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
>>> 
>>> padder(a, 2)
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
>>> padder(a, 3)
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Aforementioned approach in one line:

```
np.insert(a, np.repeat(np.arange(a.shape[1] + 1), n*2)[n:-n], 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: I like this solution but it doesn't seem to work for the general case (should have specified in my question that it's not always a padding of 1), when i adjust the repeats in np.repeat they don't remain consistent, is there a more general solution along these lines?

Comment: @James Yes, in that case you need to multiply the repeat argument by 2 for each more 1 repeat. And change the slice notations too.

Comment: @James Check out the edit for an example with more than 1 padding.

Comment: Could you convert to a function format with the pad length as a param? Would love to time these!

Answer (score 7):

Here's an approach using `zeros-initialization` -

```
def padcols(arr,padlen):
    N = 1+2*padlen
    m,n = arr.shape
    out = np.zeros((m,N*n),dtype=arr.dtype)
    out[:,padlen+np.arange(n)*N] = arr
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [118]: arr
Out[118]: 
array([[21, 14, 23],
       [52, 70, 90],
       [40, 57, 11],
       [71, 33, 78]])

In [119]: padcols(arr,1)
Out[119]: 
array([[ 0, 21,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0, 23,  0],
       [ 0, 52,  0,  0, 70,  0,  0, 90,  0],
       [ 0, 40,  0,  0, 57,  0,  0, 11,  0],
       [ 0, 71,  0,  0, 33,  0,  0, 78,  0]])

In [120]: padcols(arr,2)
Out[120]: 
array([[ 0,  0, 21,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0,  0,  0, 23,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 52,  0,  0,  0,  0, 70,  0,  0,  0,  0, 90,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 40,  0,  0,  0,  0, 57,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 71,  0,  0,  0,  0, 33,  0,  0,  0,  0, 78,  0,  0]])
```

---

### Benchmarking

In this section, I am benchmarking on runtime and memory usage the approach posted in this post : `padcols` and [@Kasramvd's solution func : `padder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39018893/3293881) on a decent sized array for various padding lengths.

**Timing profiling**

```
In [151]: arr = np.random.randint(10,99,(300,300))
           # Representative of original `3x3` sized array just bigger

In [152]: %timeit padder(arr,1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.56 ms per loop

In [153]: %timeit padcols(arr,1)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.13 ms per loop

In [154]: %timeit padder(arr,2)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.82 ms per loop

In [155]: %timeit padcols(arr,2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.66 ms per loop

In [156]: %timeit padder(arr,3)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.83 ms per loop

In [157]: %timeit padcols(arr,3)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.11 ms per loop
```

**Memory profiling**

Script used for these memory tests -

```
import numpy as np
from memory_profiler import profile

arr = np.random.randint(10,99,(300,300))
padlen = 1 # Edited to 1,2,3 for the three cases
n = padlen

@profile(precision=10)
def padder():    
    x, y = arr.shape
    indices = np.repeat(np.arange(y+1), n*2)[n:-n]
    return np.insert(arr, indices, 0, axis=1)
    
@profile(precision=10)
def padcols():    
    N = 1+2*padlen
    m,n = arr.shape
    out = np.zeros((m,N*n),dtype=arr.dtype)
    out[:,padlen+np.arange(n)*N] = arr
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    padder()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    padcols()
```

Memory usage output -

Case # 1:

```
$ python -m memory_profiler timing_pads.py
Filename: timing_pads.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     8  42.4492187500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB   @profile(precision=10)
     9                             def padder():    
    10  42.4492187500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       x, y = arr.shape
    11  42.4492187500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       indices = np.repeat(np.arange(y+1), n*2)[n:-n]
    12  44.7304687500 MiB   2.2812500000 MiB       return np.insert(arr, indices, 0, axis=1)


Filename: timing_pads.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    14  42.8750000000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB   @profile(precision=10)
    15                             def padcols():    
    16  42.8750000000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       N = 1+2*padlen
    17  42.8750000000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       m,n = arr.shape
    18  42.8750000000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       out = np.zeros((m,N*n),dtype=arr.dtype)
    19  44.6757812500 MiB   1.8007812500 MiB       out[:,padlen+np.arange(n)*N] = arr
    20  44.6757812500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       return out
```

Case # 2:

```
$ python -m memory_profiler timing_pads.py
Filename: timing_pads.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     8  42.3710937500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB   @profile(precision=10)
     9                             def padder():    
    10  42.3710937500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       x, y = arr.shape
    11  42.3710937500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       indices = np.repeat(np.arange(y+1), n*2)[n:-n]
    12  46.2421875000 MiB   3.8710937500 MiB       return np.insert(arr, indices, 0, axis=1)


Filename: timing_pads.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    14  42.8476562500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB   @profile(precision=10)
    15                             def padcols():    
    16  42.8476562500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       N = 1+2*padlen
    17  42.8476562500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       m,n = arr.shape
    18  42.8476562500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       out = np.zeros((m,N*n),dtype=arr.dtype)
    19  46.1289062500 MiB   3.2812500000 MiB       out[:,padlen+np.arange(n)*N] = arr
    20  46.1289062500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       return out
```

Case # 3:

```
$ python -m memory_profiler timing_pads.py
Filename: timing_pads.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     8  42.3906250000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB   @profile(precision=10)
     9                             def padder():    
    10  42.3906250000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       x, y = arr.shape
    11  42.3906250000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       indices = np.repeat(np.arange(y+1), n*2)[n:-n]
    12  47.4765625000 MiB   5.0859375000 MiB       return np.insert(arr, indices, 0, axis=1)


Filename: timing_pads.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    14  42.8945312500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB   @profile(precision=10)
    15                             def padcols():    
    16  42.8945312500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       N = 1+2*padlen
    17  42.8945312500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       m,n = arr.shape
    18  42.8945312500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       out = np.zeros((m,N*n),dtype=arr.dtype)
    19  47.4648437500 MiB   4.5703125000 MiB       out[:,padlen+np.arange(n)*N] = arr
    20  47.4648437500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       return out
```

Comment: This is not a memory efficient approach, at least, when you are initializing an array contain zeroes!

Comment: @Kasramvd The output array is expected to be of that shape, so I don't see why this should be inefficient.

Comment: Indeed but you are creating extra items with the length of you array that should be replace, later.

Comment: @Kasramvd Yes that indexing part would be most time consuming in this solution as initialization part should be comparatively negligible

Comment: Nice benchmark, but note that optimization is always about 2 things, memory and runtime, which based on our need we care about one of them more.

Comment: @Kasramvd Damn!! I learnt a lot about memory profiling along the way. Check out the edited section on your memory efficiency issue! :)

Comment: Indeed :-) as you can see by increasing the precision the difference gets lower, this means for huge arrays my approach is more optimized in terms of memory usage. But we shouldn't forget that sometimes [Worse is better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse_is_better). Which distinction between these is up to OP! Anyway good job++!

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the array, convert each 1 to [0, 1, 0], then reshape again to 3 rows. In the following code the ones array is in var a:

```
a = np.ones([3,3])

b = [[0, x, 0] for x in a.ravel()]
c = np.reshape(b, (a.shape[0], -1))

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem with time and memory comparison of these methods is that it treats `insert` as a blackbox.  But that function is Python code that can be read and replicated.  While it can handle various kinds of inputs, in this case I think it

- generates a `new` target array of the right size
- calculates the indices of the columns that take the fill value
- creates a mask for the old values
- copies the fill values to new
- copies the old values to new

There's no way that `insert` can be more efficient than `Divakar's` `padcols`.

Let's see if I can clearly replicate `insert`:

```
In [255]: indices = np.repeat(np.arange(y + 1), 1*factor*2)[1*factor:-1*factor]
In [256]: indices
Out[256]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
In [257]: numnew = len(indices)
In [258]: order = indices.argsort(kind='mergesort')
In [259]: indices[order] += np.arange(numnew)
In [260]: indices
Out[260]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19,
       20])
```

these are the columns that will take the `0` fill value.

```
In [266]: new = np.empty((3,21),a.dtype)
In [267]: new[:,indices] = 0     # fill
# in this case with a lot of fills
# np.zeros((3,21),a.dtype)   would be just as good

In [270]: old_mask = np.ones((21,),bool)
In [271]: old_mask[indices] = False
In [272]: new[:,old_mask] = a

In [273]: new
Out[273]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The main difference from `padcols` is this uses a boolean mask for indexing as opposed to column numbers.